# Newly added images not showing in "Desktop Pictures"

Tags: macos, desktop

I have just bought myself a new Mac and am finding the new OS a little alien at present.  I've just downloaded a new background screen and moved it to the /Library/Desktop Pictures/ folder.  However when I go to "System Preferences"->"Desktop&Screen Saver" none of my newly downloaded images are showing up for me to choose a new background image.

Any idea why this is happening as I was told that that folder was the default location where all desktop background images are stored (NB: I do NOT want to leave my newly downloaded images in any other folder but the default one)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `/Library/Desktop Pictures/` try `~/Library/Desktop Pictures/`
That's where mine seem to be stored.

Mac has 2 [or more] libraries, one for the whole system & one for each user.
The tilde ~ is a shortcut for `boot_drive/users/my_name/` - your Home folder.
[Think of it like using `%appdata%` etc. from the Start menu in Windows]

The `/Library` folder is hidden by default, but easily accessible.

Quickest way to get to it from the Finder is

- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>N</kbd>  for new window
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go...
- Copy/paste `~/Library` or `~/Library/Desktop Pictures/` in this particular case.

If you find that you need to access it more frequently, there are methods to show it permanently, but I'll leave that for another question.

***Edit***
From discussion, this folder may not exist by default... so here's how to make then add to Desktop & Screen Saver.

- Open ~/Library then
- <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Shift</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>  for New Folder. Name it Desktop Pictures. Drop your intended backgrounds in there.
- Open System Prefs > Desktop & Screen Saver
- Drag the new Desktop pictures folder to 'Folders' in the list on the left of Desktop & Screen Saver
- It should be immediately usable as a source.

[image]

Comment: It appears that although ~/Library is there ~/Library/Desktop Pictures/ isn't.  I'm using Maverick on a Macbook Pro.  Here is what it shows when I try to go to that location: http://i.imgur.com/m6pXOT3.png

Comment: hmm... interesting.. OK, adding to my answer so I can use pics... few ways to do it, this might be easiest.